# Send file to browser from string using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, pdfkit

I am using PDFKit and socket.io in a node.js project to generate a pdf when a user clicks a button on the front end. How do I stream or otherwise send the resulting pdf to the end-user from here? I'd rather avoid saving the file to the file system and then having to delete it later if I can... hoping to stream it somehow.

```
socket.on('customerRequestPDF', function(){              
    doc = new PDFDocument;        

    doc.text('Some text goes here', 100, 100);

    //I could do this but would rather avoid it
    doc.write('output.pdf');

    doc.output(function(string) {
        //ok I have the string.. now what?

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A websocket isn't really the appropriate mechanism to deliver the PDF.  Just use a regular HTTP request.

```
// assuming Express, but works similarly with the vanilla HTTP server
app.get('/pdf/:token/filename.pdf', function(req, res) {
    var doc = new PDFDocument();
    // ...

    doc.output(function(buf) { // as of PDFKit v0.2.1 -- see edit history for older versions
        res.writeHead(200, {
             'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
             'Cache-Control': 'private',
             'Content-Length': buf.length
        });
        res.end(buf);
    });
});
```

Now a word of warning: This PDF library is broken.  As of version 0.2.1, the output is a proper `Buffer`, but it uses the deprecated `binary` string encoding internally instead of `Buffer`s.  (Previous versions gave you the binary-encoded string.)  From the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer):

> `'binary'` - A way of encoding raw binary data into strings by using only the first 8 bits of each character. This encoding method is deprecated and should be avoided in favor of `Buffer` objects where possible. This encoding will be removed in future versions of Node.

This means that when node removes the binary string encoding, the library will stop working.

Comment: As of [this](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/pull/166) pull request, `doc.output` now returns a buffer instead of a binary string.

Comment: @devongovett, thanks for the update.  I noticed, however, that the binary string encoding is still used internally.  This means the library will break when node eventually removes support for the encoding.